# MySQL query - get a list of ALL WP admin email addresses for all WP sites on server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, cpanel

I have a lot of WP websites set up on my server, and I'm trying to get a list of admin email addresses registered for all of the WP sites.

The server uses WHM/cPanel, and MariaDB.

I'd hoped WordPress Toolkit could do this out of the box, but it doesn't seem to be able to.

I'm an SQL noob, and I've only gotten as far as this for my SQL query, for a single DB:

```
SELECT option_value
  FROM `database_name`.`wp_options`
 WHERE option_name="admin_email"
```

Another problem is, lots of the WP databases on the server don't use the standard wp_ table prefix, but instead use a random string, so I also need a way of using a wildcard in the table name  like

> *_options

So my 2 problems are:

1. Make the query loop across ALL databases on the server
2. make the query use a wildcard in the table name

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're trying to export user's email then use any export plugin. If you're trying to do something on php then use [WP_User_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) or [get_users](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) to fetch the users with your required filters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its two queries, first to generate the SQL, and then execute it.

Example setup:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database rr;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database ss;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create table ss.wp_options(option_name varchar(30), option_value varchar(30));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create table rr.rr_options(option_name varchar(30), option_value varchar(30));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> insert into ss.wp_options values ('admin_email', 'me@ss');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.003 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> insert into rr.rr_options values ('admin_email', 'me@rr');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)
```

Then use the [information_schema.TABLES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-tables-table/) to generate your query using `UNION ALL` to concatinate them:

```
SELECT group_concat(
  concat('select "', TABLE_SCHEMA, '" as db, option_value from ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' WHERE option_name="admin_email"')
 SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_options';
```

Just to show what we generate:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @sql\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@sql: select "ss" as db, option_value from ss.wp_options WHERE option_name="admin_email"
  UNION ALL select "rr" as db, option_value from rr.rr_options WHERE option_name="admin_email"
```

[Execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) runs a query, like a prepared statement without the setup and run, shutdown steps:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> execute immediate @sql;
+----+--------------+
| db | option_value |
+----+--------------+
| ss | me@ss        |
| rr | me@rr        |
+----+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: You may need to increase `group_concat_max_len` for that `GROUP_CONCAT`.